# How to remove last 8 characters in a string builder and rest of the characters append to an another string builder?

Tags: java

How to remove the 8 characters in a StringBuilder from the ending and append the rest of the characters to another StringBuilder

I tried this way, but this is not giving me the expected results

```
public class Student{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileNameEdit = "student_1733332211";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        
        String modifiedStr = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNameEdit.length(); i++) {
              char c = fileNameEdit.charAt(i);
              if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                  sb2.append(c);
                  if(sb2.length()>8) {
                      modifiedStr = sb2.substring(0, sb2.length() - 8);
                    
                  }
                  sb.append(modifiedStr);
              }
              else {

              sb.append(c);
              sb.append(modifiedStr);
             
              }
            }

        System.out.println("sb:   "+sb);
        System.out.println("sb2:  "+sb2);

    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
sb:   student_117
sb2:  1733332211
```

But the EXPECTED OUTPUT is

```
sb:   student_17
sb2:  1733332211
```

I want to remove the last 8 characters in sb2 and rest of the characters should be added to sb

Comment: `substring` does _not modify_ the string builder. `setLength` does

Comment: You seem to be grossly overestimating the complexity of your task. It's just `sb.append(fileNameEdit.substring(0, fileNameEdit.length() - 8)`. No need for any loops. By the way, the expected value for sb2 is not part of your stated requirements, or perhaps you should clarify them.

Comment: Have you considered using the String.substring() methods?

Comment: @k314159 even better, `sb.append(fileNameEdit, 0, fileNameEdit.length() - 8)`, without the need for a temporary `String`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last 8 characters from a string builder, you can use [`setLength`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength-int-) and [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#length--):

```
sb.setLength(sb.length() - 8);
```

Make sure to check for strings shorter than 8 chars or truncate to 0 in that case:

```
sb.setLength(Math.max(0, sb.length() - 8));
```

To append the content of one string builder to another string builder, [`append`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.CharSequence-) can be used directly, because `StringBuilder implements CharSequence`:

```
sb2.append(sb);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you want to split file name in 2 String Builder instance.
Sb2 will contain last 8 character and rest will be stored in SB1 .
So you can use as follows:

```
public class Student{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileNameEdit = "student_1733332211";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();


        sb2.append(fileNameEdit);
        sb.append( sb2.substring(fileNameEdit.length()-8,fileNameEdit.length()));
        sb2.delete(fileNameEdit.length()-8,fileNameEdit.length());

         System.out.println("sb:   "+sb);
        System.out.println("sb2:  "+sb2);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to append `modifiedStr` on each iteration, in you code you even append it if you dont encounter a digit.

A corrected version: https://ideone.com/TLVUdj

```
 class Student{
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileNameEdit = "student_1733332211";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
 
        for (int i = 0; i < fileNameEdit.length(); i++) {
            char c = fileNameEdit.charAt(i);
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                sb2.append(c);
            else
                sb.append(c);
        }
 
        if(sb2.length() > 8)
            sb.append(sb2.substring(0, sb2.length() - 8));
        else
            sb.append(sb2);
 
        System.out.println("sb:   " + sb);
        System.out.println("sb2:  " + sb2);
    }
}
```

to make your code more concise you may use regexps for this task:

https://ideone.com/52vJfY

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Student{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileNameEdit = "student_1733332211";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d+)$"); // first match any non digits, then the digits
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileNameEdit);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            sb.append(matcher.group(1)); // non-digt characters group
            sb2.append(matcher.group(2)); // digits part group

            if (sb2.length() > 8) {
                sb.append(sb2.substring(0, sb2.length() - 8));
            } else {
                sb.append(sb2);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("sb:   " + sb);
        System.out.println("sb2:  " + sb2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are appending a compounded *modifiedStr* to *sb*, in two of the iterations.
I believe you are intending the second instance of *modifiedStr* to be just a *"7"*, and not *"17"*.

```
i =  0, c = s, sb = s
i =  1, c = t, sb = st
i =  2, c = u, sb = stu
i =  3, c = d, sb = stud
i =  4, c = e, sb = stude
i =  5, c = n, sb = studen
i =  6, c = t, sb = student
i =  7, c = _, sb = student_
i =  8, c = 1, sb = student_, sb2 = 1
i =  9, c = 7, sb = student_, sb2 = 17
i = 10, c = 3, sb = student_, sb2 = 173
i = 11, c = 3, sb = student_, sb2 = 1733
i = 12, c = 3, sb = student_, sb2 = 17333
i = 13, c = 3, sb = student_, sb2 = 173333
i = 14, c = 2, sb = student_, sb2 = 1733332
i = 15, c = 2, sb = student_, sb2 = 17333322
i = 16, c = 1, sb = student_1, sb2 = 173333221, modifiedStr = 1
i = 17, c = 1, sb = student_117, sb2 = 1733332211, modifiedStr = 17
```

I guess you could technically just append *modifiedStr* once, after the *for-loop*.

```java
String fileNameEdit = "student_1733332211";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

String modifiedStr = "";

for (int i = 0; i < fileNameEdit.length(); i++) {
    char c = fileNameEdit.charAt(i);
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        sb2.append(c);
        if(sb2.length()>8) {
            modifiedStr = sb2.substring(0, sb2.length() - 8);

        }
    }
    else {

        sb.append(c);

    }
}

sb.append(modifiedStr);

System.out.println("sb:   "+sb);
System.out.println("sb2:  "+sb2);
```

Although, there is a much simpler way to do this.

> *"How to remove the 8 characters in a StringBuilder from the ending and append the rest of the characters to another StringBuilder ..."*

You can use the *[StringBuilder#delete](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,int))* method.

```java
String fileNameEdit = "student_1733332211";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fileNameEdit);
sb.delete(sb.length() - 8, sb.length());
```

Output

```
student_17
```

As for *sb2*, it appears you require 10 digits here, and not 8.

You can use the same *delete* method.

```java
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(fileNameEdit);
sb2.delete(0, sb2.length() - 10);
```

Output

```
1733332211
```